# Data not valid when copy-pasting the code from website

Tags: windows-xp, copy-paste

I copied an IFSC code from a website. After that, I pasted it on the ICICI bank's website into the IFSC input.

It shows that the code is not valid, but when I type in the same code manually, it will accepted.

Why is this happening, and what can I do to be able to correctly copy/paste the code?

Answer (score 1):

You may have accidentally copied some extra characters in the beginning or the end of the code, such as a whitespace.

Another option is that there are differences in the encoding of the characters, but this is usually relevant only if there are special characters in the text.

Answer (score 1):

To remove any formatting or other characters that shouldn't be there, paste the code into notepad first, then copy/paste from notepad to the ICICI site.

That way any non-text characters will be stripped out, and gives you an opportunity to remove any whitespace you picked up at the beginning and end of the text.

Note that you can do this with any field that generally only accepts text - the Start / Run field is an easily accessible field do an intermediate copy/paste into for example.  Just be aware of where you leave the data if it sensitive.